# Get a variable that is inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, variables

**I have this HTML document:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/first.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/second.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**first.js:**

```
(function(){
    var p = 9;
    ...
})();
```

How to have access and edit the p variable from **second.js** without modifying first.js? Is there a way?

Comment: You should see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your variable global using :

```
(function(){
    window.p = 9;
    ...
})();
```

Comment: `without modifying first.js`

Comment: Is there a different way without modifying first.js?

Comment: There is no way, using `var` mean your variable exist only on the scope of the function first, you can't set it to global from outside the function, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set p as global variable in first.js

```
var p;
(function(){
   p = 9;
    ...
})();
```

Comment: Is there a different way without modifying first.js?

Answer (score 0):

export your variable

```
(function(exports){
   exports.p = 9;
    ...
})(window);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion